# How to use the rails config gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have added the gem 'config' and installed the gem.
I have also add generated the config.rb file in initializer and along with them the below files generated:

```
config/settings.yml
config/settings/development.yml
config/settings/production.yml
config/settings/test.yml
```

how to use this gem.can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you share your development.yml code

Comment: App_url = 'http://localhost:3000'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define like `App_url: 'localhost:3000'`. and should not use `=` and `;`

Comment: if I use like that what you said above then i am getting error like this,

uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::APP_URL

for this path 

= link_to "#{@project.name.humanize}","#{APP_URL}#{project_path(@project)}",class: 'app_url'

Comment: You should use `Settings.APP_URL` not just `APP_URL`.

Comment: Can we change config.const_name = 'Settings' to some other name?

Comment: I don't think so. but you can try

Comment: can we move 
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
 config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
to development.yml file?

Comment: No, you cannot move everything to development.yml.
Only you can do  is `ASSETS_HOST: locahost:3000`